# How do I properly overload the operator in this specific case using C++

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ programming and am having trouble implementing this operator overloading. It gives the error that no operator "<<" matches these operands.

```
class class1{

public:
    bool operator==(class1 &);
    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &, class1 &);

private:
    string name;
};

/*Friend ostream & operator <<*/
ostream & operator << (ostream & os, class1 & obj){
    os << obj.name;
    return os;
}
```

Someone mentioned I need another overloaded operator, but I can't figure out how to make it work with another overloaded operator

Comment: `friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &, const class1 &);`

Comment: What line gives the error?

Comment: @aschepler The error is on os<<obj.name

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that adds an 'invalid identifier' error

Comment: Maybe you are missing `#include <string>` ? To get a good answer , post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @M.M What a simple thing to forget. I included the string library and that fixed my problem. If I run into further problems, I may restructure my code and follow one of the answers below. Thank you for everyone's help. It is much appreciated.

Comment: @DylanVizcarra cool, I have written up an answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is the situation with your code; you have a private member string variable within your class where no outside object can set this variable. Your class does not contain a defined constructor nor a setting method. When I tried your code I had to change your operator declaration and definition from this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, class1& obj );
```

to this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, const class1& obj );
```

in order for it to compile. However when it came to building the project I was getting a Linker Error of an unresolved identifier. What was happening here is that the ostream object that you are declaring as a friend to your class object does know about the private member string but it can not do anything with it since this string is empty or not valid. I changed your class to this:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class class1 {
    friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& out, const class1& other );

private:
    std::string m_strName;

public:
    explicit class1( std::string& strName ) : m_strName( strName ) {}

    void setName( std::string& strName ) { m_strName = strName; }
    std::string getName() const { return m_strName; }
};

std::ostream& operator << ( std::ostream& out, class1& obj ) {
    out << obj.m_strName << std::endl;
    // out << obj.getName() << std::endl;
    return out;
}

int main() {
    class1 a( std::string( "class1" ) );
    std::cout << a << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Press any key to quit" << std::endl;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles, builds, links and executes properly and displays appropriate text and exits with a value of 0 for no errors. I am using MSV2013 on a Win7 machine. The main issue was that since your class had no way to populate its string member upon construction the ostream operator object could not resolve the variable in use.

Answer (score 1):

The overload `operator<<(std::ostream&, std::string)` is actually defined by `#include <string>`.

Although `std::string` is also defined by that header, it is still possible for `std::string` to be defined but not this operator overload, if you did not include that header.

The C++ standard requires that certain headers provide certain features, but it does not prohibit that feature also being provided by another header. In your case, the compiler/library writer has decided that implementing some other feature in another header was most easily done by defining `std::string`, but it would have done this by having a separate file defining `std::string` which is included both by `<string>` and by the other header.

Answer (score 0):

remove the keyword "friend" for ostream if you intent for it to be a public member.  If your want ostream to be friend move it above public:
operator== should have two const parameter, const if you do not intend to change.

```
friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &, const class1 &);
public:
bool operator==(const class1& x, const class1& y);
```

or

```
public:
bool operator==(const class1& x, const class1& y);
ostream & operator<<(ostream &, const class1 &);
```

make operator << second parameter a const might help

```
ostream & operator << (ostream & os, const class1 & obj){
os << obj.name;
return os;
}
```